# Dropdown box game with Jquery showing results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm totally new to programming so I have a question;

I want to make a game which contains simple dropdown boxes (through html probably).

When someone selects a selection from the dropdown box, I want a separate textbox displaying 'more info' about that specific selection. I heard jquery does this.

Can anyone link me to any basic/newbie tutorials on how to do this?

Many thanks!

PS: if there are any softwares which do this more easily, can u share? much appreciated! =D

Comment: Here is a rudimentary nav bar - http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/VAfeY/. Then you could have a div somewhere on your page with the id = 'moreinfo', and use .hover over the menu to turn on text in the div. But it's better for this forum if you post some of your work, then people will be willing to critique you code.

Comment: Thanks Tim! I can use your sample as a starting point :) Can you add any sample code (a textbox with text containing a word, for example: 'Medicine') once 'Science' is clicked. Can you do that? I can then try to practise my own words, using yours as a foundation. If you can do this, then i'll be extremely grateful :D

Comment: @TimSPQR Sorry for not tagging u in the previous message. Can I have a sample of the ".hover" feature within the link u previosly sent me? I.e. once 'Science' is hovered over, i need the word 'Medicine' to display in a separate textbox. Much appreciated :)

Comment: The easiest way is to add a "title" to the anchor tag, and you'll note in this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/VAfeY/3/ - that when you hover over it, the title pops up in a little box.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/VAfeY/4/) that allows you to hover over an anchor, then jQuery reads the title from the anchor and puts it in a div.

JS

```
$( 'a' ).hover(
    function()
        {
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        $('.putmehere').text( title );
        },
    function()
        {
         $('.putmehere').html( '' );
        }
    );
```

Comment: yeh that's uber kool! :D Just one more thing, once I dragover the text, I want it to display the option AND make it clickable too - causing the selection to permanently stay there unless i click on a different word from that Category. Example: When i Drag over 'Science', I want 'A Scientist' to remain, but when I click on it, I want 'A Scientist' to remain on the screen. (this will only be removed if I click on 'English' (another word from the same dropdown list). Does that make sense? :)

Comment: What you're asking for is extremely complex. Why don't you play with the fiddles you have now, and see what you can come up with.